# Uploading An App made by a contractor

Tags: xcode4, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I've been asked to help by a friend to upload an App that a 3rd party contractor has made. The contractor has provided the source code and all the relevant files. However, since the 3rd party developer developed the app under their account, I'm having trouble uploading to the App store.

From what I can see, the bundleID and the code signing elements are not the one's listed under my friend's account. I'm having difficulty changing either in the project. When I try to compile and run the project under the simulator, it seems to be working fine though.

What are the proper steps to "convert" the current project to my friend's account so he can upload it to the App Store?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
JC

Answer (score 0):

Your friend will need to generate an App ID, distribution certificate and provisioning profile for your application. He will only be able to do that with a paid developer account on the iOS developer site.

Without properly signing your application you will not be able to distribute it to the App Store.