# How to handle code signing for client app?

Tags: javascript, electron, code-signing, electron-builder

How do I handle code signing an `Electron` app I have developed for a client, using their credentials? I've searched prior questions and have not seen this issue adequately addressed ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951874/apple-appstore-and-developers-identification-policy/5952141#5952141), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434884/how-do-i-code-sign-ios-app-using-xcode-for-clients), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581769/uploading-an-app-made-by-a-contractor)). I am doing this through `Electron-builder` for both OSX and Windows. I am focusing on OSX right now.

My client is non-technical and has not been able to navigate the Apple Developer Center process for generating provisioning profiles, etc. They provided me their login details but the 2-factor authentication is a headache. They also added me as a "team member" but that only allows me to generate `Development` certificates.

Short of sitting at the client's computer with them by my side, is there some other way to generate the needed certificates?